# How to configure Flyway in Spring Boot in code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Currently I have Spring + Flyway + Gradle setup. Everything works fine. Spring does its automagic to run Flyway migrations. Now we need to set 2 flags for Flyway in code, to allow out-of-order migrations, and ignore missing migrations. I can see from documentations that a class (`FlywayProperties`) exists for this, but I can't find a way to use it inside my code.

Do I need to create some bean that changes it or how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties can be configured directly in the Spring Boot `application.properties` or `application.yml` as follows:

application.properties:

```
spring.flyway.ignore-missing-migrations = true
spring.flyway.out-of-order = true
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    ignore-missing-migrations: true
    out-of-order: true
```

The full list of supported Flyway properties can be found in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-data-migration).

Answer (score 0):

For sure there are other maybe easier ways but I just can give a snippet how we do it via SpringApplicationBuilder

```
SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
Map<String, Object> flywayConfig = new HashMap<>();
flywayConfig.put("spring.flyway.enabled", "true");
flywayConfig.put("spring.flyway.locations", "classpath:flyway/oracle/migration");
builder.properties(flywayConfig);
```

Check here for configuring the Flyway object directly: [flyway outOfOrder is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388897/flyway-outoforder-is-not-working-as-expected)